# Products Search Criteria

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

I am building catalog of my site. I have medicines with generic and brand names like below

[image]

Generic Name is an attribute name and it's searchable.
when I search `Sildenafil` it shows all products having the same attribute value(Viagra and Sildenafil).

How can I search products on the basis of product names so that when I search `Viagra` it should returns `Viagra` as well as `Sildenafil` and vice versa since both have the same Generic Name?

Comment: check this file https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml

Comment: Is Item Name attribute also searchable?

Comment: @dudzio yes the item name is basically the product name. So yes its is searchable.

Comment: According to the data there is no logical way that all presented items will be in results when searching with `Viagra` keyword. You need to implement another attribute like `search_words` with both `Viagra` and `Sildenafil` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try this with the usage of synonyms :) not the most 'orthodox' way, but it should work as a workaround until you find a better option.

Please refer to https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/search-synonyms.html for further details.

Comment: Thank you! it is working now using sysnonyms.

Comment: you are most welcome :)